# How to swipe item from recycler view without remove it from the screen

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have 2-way swipe options, left swipe for delete and right swipe for other action.

I want the right swipe won't dismiss the item, after the swiping the item should go back to where he was.

How can I implement this?

Here is my ItemTouchHelper class (I'm not sure if you'll need more code, if you are please leave a comment and I'll add the relevant code)

**ItemTouchHelper:**

```
class ArticleItemTouchHelper(
    context: Context,
    private val adapter: ArticleListAdapter
) : ItemTouchHelper.Callback() {


    override fun getMovementFlags(
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    ): Int {

        val flags = ItemTouchHelper.START or ItemTouchHelper.END

        return makeMovementFlags(0, flags)
    }

    override fun onMove(
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
        target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    ): Boolean {
        return false // We don't want support moving items up/down
    }

    override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
        if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.START) {
            adapter.onSwipedLeft(viewHolder.adapterPosition)
        } else if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.END) {
            adapter.onSwipedRight(viewHolder.adapterPosition)
        }
    }

    override fun isLongPressDragEnabled(): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun isItemViewSwipeEnabled(): Boolean {
        return !adapter.isMultiSelectionActive()
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add your adapter code here please?

Comment: since the item is not being removed from the dataset (on right swipe) try calling notifyItemChanged(viewholder.adapterposition).

Answer (score 2):

I added `adapter.notifyItemChanged(position)` to the end of the `onSwiped()` method to achieve the goal.

As the data set is not changed by myself, so the item is still present for the adapter the whole item will move back to the initial position.

In your case, it would be like this:

```
override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
        if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.START) {
            adapter.onSwipedLeft(viewHolder.adapterPosition)
        } else if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.END) {
            adapter.onSwipedRight(viewHolder.adapterPosition)
        }

        adapter.notifyItemChanged(viewHolder.adapterPosition)
    }
```

[image: Sample recording from device]